# Why undo in android studio isn't working?

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgaBI.png)

also it is not showing here after making a change. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try to Invalidate the caches, it worked for me
[image]